# RackUnit check-eq? returns false for equal Strings

Tags: racket, rackunit

I am a little bit puzzled with RackUnit's `check-eq?` returning false for equal strings.

This is the code I am trying:

```
#lang racket

(require rackunit)

(define (get-output proc)
  (let ([out (open-output-string)])
    (parameterize ([current-output-port out])
      (proc)
      (get-output-string out))))

(define output (get-output
                (λ () (display "hello"))))

(check-eq? output "hello")
```

Running this test results in this error:

```
--------------------
. FAILURE
name:       check-eq?
location:   unsaved-editor:14:0
actual:     "hello"
expected:   "hello"
--------------------
```

I thought I understood the meaning of `eq?` but it seems I'm still missing something... why is this failing?

I know that `get-output-string` calls [bytes->string/utf8](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/bytestrings.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._bytes-~3estring%2Futf-8%29%29), which returns something that passes the `string?` contract, so I assumed this should work when comparing to a literal string.

Answer (score 3):

Oh, looks like I mixed up `eq?` and `equal?`...

`eq?` compares by memory reference.

The more lenient one is the longer one, `equal?` which compares by value, roughly.

The docs, as usual, [explain this](https://docs.racket-lang.org/rosette-guide/sec_equality.html) quite well. [Here](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/booleans.html) more details about `eq?`, `equal?` and their weird friend, `eqv?`.